# Google Analytics Issue

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I was looking over a friends script and he used the Google Analytics tracking code :

```
var _gaq = [
        ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X'],
        ['_trackPageview']
    ];
    (function(d, t) {
        var g = d.createElement(t),
            s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src = ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s)
    }(document, 'script'));
```

in this way ( or something similar ) :

```
var SOMEOBJECT = {
    _gaq : [],
    account_code : "",

    ...

    init : function() {
        ...
    }

    ...

    _gaq.push(SOMEOBJECT.account_code);

    ...
}
```

and some more code to create the same tracking code but in a different way ( because it needs to be reused on many other pages and for various stuff ).

The idea is that the scope variable `_gaq` didn't seem to be present in the console, so Analytics didn't received any data. So what could be going wrong ? Sorry for not having more code, but this is from what I remember and I was very curios why it didn't work (:

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: @roel ~ At this moment I don't have a lot of details on what is happening, I will have to tell my friend to send me the code so I can be more specific. But what I got is that the `_gaq` variable wasn't present in the DOM, if I tried to type in the console `._gaq` it seemed like it wasn't declared even though it is. If I had an object instead of an array it worked fine, but the `_gaq` variable needs to be an array as it says in the google analytics tracking code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your code looks good... just a refactoring of the normal Google Analytics async code.

I'm not sure sure about the second part of your code... normally `_gaq` is a global object initialized something like

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

which initializes a global `_gaq` as an array *if it hasn't been initialized already*.
Once the Google Analytics code is loaded, the array is replaced with an object containing a `push` method that executes commands.

Take a look at the docs for [the _gaq Global Object](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq) and the [push](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push) method.

Comment: ~ precisely, the variable it's initializes like that `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` . But I'm not quite sure why he had problems with that, I suppose doing this `_gaq : _gaq || []` it's not possible or semantically correct ?

Comment: The problem is you end up with two different `_gaq`s -- the global _gaq used by the analytics code & a second _gaq that's defined as a property of SOMEOBJECT.

Comment: What if you remove the _gaq initialization from the SOMEOBJECT code, and init it outside... something like:
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    var SOMEOBJECT = { ...

Comment: That could work :) Though I'd prefer keeping it inside the object ... I'll try that to see what happens as soon as I get my hands on the whole code ( it's a big .net project so I can only run locally from the TFS )